# How to set expectations on classes for doing unit tests involving nested calls?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-testing

I'm working on testing a class using Robolectric. This is my use case:

There are 3 classes A, B and C. There is a library that i make calls to from C like this:

```
<Lib-class>.getInstance().doSomething(Object param);
```

Class C is defined as:

```
public class C {

  public void xyz(Object data) {
     <Lib-class>.getInstance().doSomething(data);
  }
}
```

I am testing class A. The test for Class A has a method called

```
@Test
public void testDo() {

  C c = new C();
  String x = "abc";
  c.xyz(x);

}
```

I want to verify two things:

- The doSomething() method of the library class was called
- The doSomething() method was called with the same parameters that I passed (tests the flow)

I cannot use Mockito to mock the library class because it is final.

I wrote code to shadow the library class, but the implementation of the shadow method is called only if I call .getInstance().doSomething(x) from my test class for A, and not when it is called from A -> C -> LibraryClass

How can I make sure that calling c.xyz(x) would result in my shadow class getting called??

I have used @Config(shadows = {ShadowLibClass.class}) for my test. Am using a custom test runner too. The basic shadow logic works.

Answer (score 0):

Shadow for nested calls work, but don't know why not at you. Had you ovewrite the instrumentation Setup  class definition and returning it within the createSetup method and added your shadowed class as 'should be instrumented'?

Exist multiple doSomething metheds with different method params? Maybe just the wrong method is shadowed.